# Installing TensorFlow using Anaconda/Miniconda

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, conda

I am trying to install TensorFlow 2.3 on macOS. I downloaded and installed Miniconda and I realized that the best I can get there is TensorFlow 2.0. As far as I know, it has been quite a while since version 2.0 was released.

Maybe someone of you here knows if there is any plan to update these conda packages, and why is it taking so long to do it?

Thank you very much for the information!

PD: I know I can still get TensorFlow 2.3 by using `pip install tensorflow`, but I normally prefer to use conda if I have the chance.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't the right place for this question. If you were trying to install tensorflow and getting an error message you don't understand, or looking for help installing it without depending on conda packages, then someone here could help. I would suggest contacting Anaconda, Inc. or looking for someone in the tensorflow or anaconda community to take on the packaging work.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the community of anacoda needs just longer to adapt all the packages, which are released. So when a new TF version is released, it will be first released on github, then on platforms like pip. Then the community of Anaconda has to use that release and implement it into conda. Sometimes the community of [conda-forge](https://conda-forge.org/) is faster. If you want to stick with anaconda for installing packages, you might want to add conda-forge as source and get tf from there.

```
conda config --add channels conda-forge
conda config --set channel_priority strict
conda install <package-name>*
```

*taken from conda-forge.org

Comment: I know about the conda-forge community, but it seems that for this particular case they are way behind. They do not even have TensorFlow 2.0 available there. They are stuck with version 1.14 for all macOS, Windows and Linux.

source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow

Comment: Then I would recommend you to use Anacoda or miniconda. I created a blog-post about how to set an environment for using Deep Learning tools, which might be interesting for you: https://michaeljanz-data.science/further-topics/setup-python-environment-with-anaconda-git-bash-for-deep-learning-2/